# How to write a type in typescript in which the type of one value will depend on the type of another value in the object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to write a type 'PROP' for this to work

```
let a : PROP = {
    type: String,
    default: 'STR'
} // OK

let a : PROP = {
    type: String,
    default: []
} // ERR
```

In general, a type in which the value of the default field will depend on the value of the field type. I tried to write

```
type CleanPropTypes = typeof Array | typeof Object | typeof Function | typeof Boolean | typeof String

type PROP<T = CleanPropTypes, U = any> = {
     type:T,
     default?: U extends T
}

var b : PROP = {
    type:Array,
    default:[]
}
```

[example](https://tsplay.dev/NddZMN)

But it doesn't work. How to write this type ?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvY6km) what you're looking for?  If so, I can write up an answer.  If not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Nuts! Its works. I don`t know to hide long link. there is only one example
    let b : Prop = {
         type:Object,
         default:'STR'
    } //  must be err
But otherwise everything works great. thx a lot. I will parse your code

Comment: You can use https://tsplay.dev to shorten links to the TypeScript Playground, but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Maybe you added the comment prematurely?

Comment: [only counter example](http://tsplay.dev/WyOnxN)

Comment: I guess you can't infer `object` from the `Object` constructor, so you need to special case it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4yz7w) maybe.  Of course you could just do it manually [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYepN) instead.  If one of those works for you let me know and I can write it up.

Comment: I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx6Xzw) completely solves this problem. this is your last link

Comment: the only thing that confuses me ( this is no longer on the question )  Why 
`CleanPropTypes extends infer C` but not `infer C extends CleanPropTypes` [link](https://tsplay.dev/NDz7jW)

Comment: `infer C extends CleanPropTypes` is not valid syntax; I'm using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy `CleanPropTypes` into a generic type parameter, and then `C extends (...args: any) => infer I` to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the operation across the union in `C`.  I will write up an answer soon.

Comment: Also I added `typeof String` to your `CleanPropTypes` because your example code seems to use `String` in there.  Could you change that part of your question so I don't have to explain why my answer has added something to `CleanPropTypes`?

Comment: change done, thx

Comment: now I figured it out every line your solution )

Answer (score 1):

The right definition for `Prop` should probably be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of valid `type`/`default` pairs corresponding to each [primitive wrapper object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) creator in `CleanPropTypes`.  Something like this:

```
type Prop = {
    type: ArrayConstructor;
    default?: unknown[] | undefined;
} | {
    type: ObjectConstructor;
    default?: object | undefined;
} | {
    type: FunctionConstructor;
    default?: Function | undefined;
} | {
    type: BooleanConstructor;
    default?: boolean | undefined;
} | {
    type: StringConstructor;
    default?: string | undefined;
}
```

That behaves how you'd like:

```
let good1: Prop = {
    type: String,
    default: 'STR'
} // okay

let bad1: Prop = {
    type: String,
    default: []
} // error

var good2: Prop = {
    type: Array,
    default: []
} // okay

var bad2: Prop = {
    type: Object,
    default: "oops"
} // error
```

---

Now, you could manually define `Prop`, but if you'd like the compiler to *compute* `Prop` in terms of `CleanPropTypes`, you can mostly do so by treating each of those
primitive wrappers as a function that produces a value of the relevant primitive type.  For example:

```
type Prop2 = CleanPropTypes extends infer C ?
    C extends (...args: any) => infer R ?
    { type: C, default?: R }
    : never : never;
```

Here I'm using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) twice.  The first time, `CleanPropTypes extends infer C ? ... : never` basically just *copies* the `CleanPropTypes` specific type into the new *type parameter* `C`.  Then, when we write `C extends (...args: any) => infer R ? ... : never`, we are getting the return type `R` of the function in `C`.  The reason we do the copying first is so that `C extends ... ? ... : ...` becomes a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), breaking the `CleanPropTypes` union into individual elements, and evaluating `{ type: C, default?: R }` for each such element, and then putting them back together in a union.

Anyway, this is *almost* what you want:

```
/* type Prop2 = {
    type: ArrayConstructor;
    default?: unknown[] | undefined;
} | {
    type: ObjectConstructor;
    default?: any;
} | {
    type: FunctionConstructor;
    default?: Function | undefined;
} | {
    type: BooleanConstructor;
    default?: boolean | undefined;
} | {
    type: StringConstructor;
    default?: string | undefined;
} */
```

Everything is correct except for the `ObjectContructor` element.  Here, the `default` property is of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) which allows anything, except for the more correct [`object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) which only allows non-primitives.  I assume the [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) for `Object` predates the introduction of `object`.  See [ms/TS#13741](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13741) for some discussion about this.

Anyway, since that one isn't working for us, we can do just that one manually, and then produce the rest from `Exclude<CleanPropTypes, ObjectConstructor>`, where we use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to remove `ObjectConstructor` from the union:

```
type Prop3 = (Exclude<CleanPropTypes, typeof Object> extends infer C ?
    C extends (...args: any) => infer I ?
    { type: C, default?: I } : never : never
) | { type: ObjectConstructor, default?: object }
```

And that produces the same type as `Prop` above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-6AjnA0-+riB4CX9YwkMdj6HsgV9T9PHmaQDjuZooQ2W053efYlkOX5UTfKYwNmC1rm+P9rzlRC+k+G5tDQ190XOcDpXBEx8OhG9ZyArxEVMF9ijRM5d05ZNIEPMAAGYHCbABRfMBDgSQogAHkzFBs3wAgZ2UDh6iGIcCyLEth2QctdVratwlrTSG2bNsWw7LsoB7ftiCHEddQASXHcJJzmGAZzvPpnMqDctygPy1QsftpinNTGnuK9oU8u0+gGBphAxKwLCAA)